# How to convert dynamic html page to pdf in Django?

Tags: html, django, pdf

I have a task to convert a dynamic html page into a pdf document.
What we have:

1. dogovor application.
2. Formadogovora.html page which contains a form with the required fields.
3. The page dogovortemplate.html which contains text into which the values ​​from the form should be substituted on the page formadogovora.html and a pdf document should be immediately generated.
4. The dogovor/forms.py file contains:

```
from django import forms

     class DogovorUserForm(forms.Form):
         sellername = forms.CharField(label='Seller's name',
     widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-input'}))
         yachtclass = forms.CharField(label='Yacht Class',
     widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-input'}))
```

5. The dogovor/urls.py file contains:

```
from django.urls import path
     from . import views

     app_name = 'dogovor'

     urlpatterns = [
         path('formadogovora/', views.formadogovora_user,
     name='formadogovora'),

     ]
```

6. The file dogovor/views.py contains:

```
def formadogovora_user(request):
         form = DogovorUserForm() # Import the form class from forms.py
         return render(request, 'dogovor/formadogovora.html', {'form': form})
```

7. Contents of the formadogovora.html file:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% load static %}

    {% block title %}Form of agreement{% endblock %}

    {% block content %}
    <h1>Form of agreement</h1>
    <form method="post">
         {% csrf_token %}
         {{ form.as_p }}
         <button type="submit">Generate document</button>
    </form>
    {% endblock %}
```

8. Contents of the dogovortemplate.html file:

```
<h1>Agreement</h1>
    <p>This agreement is concluded between:</p>
    <ul>
         <li>Seller: {{ dogovor.sellername }}</li>
         <li>Yacht class: {{ dogovor.yachtclass }}</li>
    </ul>
    <p>About the subject of the agreement:</p>
    <ul>
         <li>The Contractor undertakes to perform work on the development and implementation of software for the Customer.</li>
         <li>The customer undertakes to pay for the work performed in accordance with the terms of the contract.</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Contract duration:</p>
    <ul>
         <li>The Agreement comes into force from the moment of its signing and is valid for one year.</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Signatures of the parties:</p>
    <ul>
         <li>Customer: _____________________</li>
         <li>Performer: _____________________</li>
         <li>Captain: _____________________</li>
    </ul>
```

The formadogovora.html page should open at the path mysite.com/dogovor/formadogovora.html. After filling out the fields and clicking on the “Generate document” button, a new tab should open with a pdf document based on the document template.html template.
How to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Try using weasyprint library. It converts an html to a pdf and it has support for django applications.
For tutorial see this link:
https://micropyramid.com/blog/generate-pdf-files-from-html-in-django-using-weasyprint

Also here is official website:
https://weasyprint.org/